# Mock Fetch API in unit test onClick method in React

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, fetch-api

I created a JS Bin for the code that I am trying to test: https://jsbin.com/zaqiyuw/edit?html,js,output. I have a button that calls a method in the component. The component uses fetch to call an api and then setState based upon what is returned. I can't seem to mock it properly.

When the test runs it calls the method and sets state in the getPingMsg() to { ping: "loading..."} but it never sets it to the value it gets from the then on fetch in the test. Any ideas what the issue might be?

I am using sinon, enzyme and jest. Here is what I've tried:

```
describe('<App />', function() {

    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    it('should return 1 onClick', ()=> {
        sinon.stub(window, 'fetch');
        function jsonOk (body) {
            const mockResponse = 
                new window.Response(JSON.stringify(body), {
                    status: 200,
                    headers: {
                         'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                 });
             return Promise.resolve(mockResponse);
         }
         window.fetch.returns(
             jsonOk({ping: 1})
         );
         wrapper.update();
         expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ ping: 'No Request Yet' }); //this works
         wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
         expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ ping: 1 }); //this doesn't
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. It turns out that it was setting state but AFTER I was calling the expect statement (DOH)! With your help this test works:

```
it('should return pong onClick', (done)=> {
    sinon.stub(window, 'fetch');
    function jsonOk (body) {
        const mockResponse = new window.Response(JSON.stringify(body));
        return Promise.resolve(mockResponse);
    }
    window.fetch.returns((jsonOk({ping: 1})));
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ ping: 'No Request Yet' });
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    setTimeout(function() {expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ ping: 1 }); console.log(wrapper.state()); done();}, 10);
});
```